# Magento 2 : Add attribute options programmatically in custom attribute

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute

I have created custom attribute which type is **Select**. That attribute is available inside custom eav entity type. I want to add attribute options inside that attribute. How to do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://webkul.com/blog/programmatically-add-options-attribute-magento2/ please check this, if it is helpful for you

Answer (score 2):

You can create options for select element while creating the attribute.

Let's take an example:

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        /**
         * Add attributes to the eav_attribute
         */
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'product_select_attribute');
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'product_custom_attribute');

        $statusOptions = 'Namespace\Modulename\Model\Config\Source\StatusOptions';
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'product_select_attribute',
            [
                'group' => 'Custom Product Attribute',
                'type' => 'int',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Product Status',
                'input' => 'select',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => $statusOptions,
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

In above code i used  `'source' => $statusOptions,` it is defind select option dynamically.

You need to create Model file for define our custom option of select box, `$statusOptions = ‘Namespace\Modulename\Model\Config\Source\StatusOptions’;`

create StatusOptions.php file under Model and define our enable and disable option value.

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Model/Config/Source/StatusOptions.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource;

class StatusOptions extends AbstractSource
{
    /**
     * Get all options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if (null === $this->_options) {
            $this->_options=[
                                ['label' => __('Enable'), 'value' => 1],
                                ['label' => __('Disable'), 'value' => 0]
                            ];
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

Run below command :

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush
>
> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

---

**Update :**

Change below function code for dynamic data

```
public function getAllOptions()
{
    $collection = $this->CollectionFactory->create();
    foreach ($collection as $item) {
        $this->_options[] = [
                'label' => __($item['title']),
                'value' => $item['id'],
            ];
    }

    return $this->_options;
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Is it possible to add from admin panel? as like product attribute.

Comment: Because, I want to make it dynamically so.

Comment: If you want to modify select option value then you can change in `StatusOptions.php` file

Comment: And you may write dynamic logic inside `StatusOptions.php`

Comment: Hmmm...!!! Maybe possible.

Comment: For dynamic, you have to modify `public function getAllOptions()`

Comment: See my updated  answer to get dynamic data in options.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93299/discussion-between-emipro-technologies-pvt-ltd-and-chirag-patel).

Comment: If my answer is useful to you then accept an answer, so it will be useful to another user.

Comment: I have similar issue over here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/313962/eav-attribute-option-and-eav-attribute-option-value-not-getting-updated-after-ad. It would be great if anyone can guide me through this